# How to retrieve Google Talk password from a registry hive?

Tags: google-talk, password-recovery

Further to [my previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/394350/how-to-retrieve-my-gmail-password-from-google-chat) ... brief summary ...

- stolen laptop
- found old harddrive
- booted from it & auto into gogole talk

but, now, presumably since the harddrive is in a different PC, Widows Vista declares it self to be invalid.

I do not have the old password, but Vista was auto-starting Gogole Talk & I could see my mails (can't answer the recovery questions)

Now I have managed to mount the harddrive externally and use NIRsoft's Reg File Export to export the registry hive HKEY_current_user\software\google, which I will post below, changing only my email address.

I imported this into the registry on the new machine and when I start Gogole Talk it shows the correct email address, but the password field is blank, despite being in the registry hive.

Does anyone know how to decrypt the password? I googled & downloaded a bunch or programs which claim to, but they could not...

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[hkey_current_user\software\google]

[hkey_current_user\software\google\Google Talk]

[hkey_current_user\software\google\Google Talk\Accounts]
"o"=hex(7):6E,00,64,00,71,00,6E,00,36,00,33,00,40,00,67,00,6D,00,61,00,69,\
00,6C,00,2E,00,63,00,6F,00,6D,00,00,00,00,00
"a"="XXXXXX@gmail.com/Talk.v1042427D83E"

[hkey_current_user\software\google\Google Talk\Accounts\XXXXXX@gmail.com]
"pw"="`somesort of password hash`"
"px"="talk.google.com"
"bpx"="talkx.l.google.c"
"ct"=dword:00000001
"k"=dword:00000001
"pt"=dword:00001466
"mailstate"=hex(3):62,ED,7D,C6,35,01,00,00,3C,5C,3A,7A,98,64,5C,13

[hkey_current_user\software\google\Google Talk\Autoupdate]
"AppPath"="C:\\Users\\user\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Google Talk\\"
"InstalledVersion"="1.0.0.104"
"UpdateURL"="http://tools.google.com/googletalk/google-talk-versioncheck.txt"
"AvailableURL"="http://dl.google.com/googletalk/googletalk-setup-upgrade.exe"
"AvailableDescription"="Google Talk Update"
"LaunchAction"="execute"
"LaunchTarget"="googletalk-setup-upgrade.exe"
"LaunchParameter"="/S upgrade"
"Signature"="1ec0c33eff4b7097749166576f09ecfdebad641e508fac40921cfe856b923bba90a8b7e66bd812fb060897920e3f9d7d00dfd4391b09d9ec2374173ffc6941820bca01916639ea2363d214e6f204914d499dfe73a9bba696976e7d5e4c8181b863b6a8546d27e8db3335fc567615b1c20ede1841b0fe064b54e56dd3054f622488d4f6114f038ea6c8150bc956f702a7655298977829baa7db346051cfa6f378d05ff4f1dbb9537a22c81b92938dfb66d5628fd4b36259dca3842cce8958e293"
"NextUpdate"=dword:4f4f9cc0

[hkey_current_user\software\google\Google Talk\Options]
"minimized"=dword:00000001
"windowrect"=hex(3):0E,01,00,00,3C,00,00,00,12,02,00,00,FE,01,00,00
"mailto_backup_handler"=""
"mailto_backup_icon"=""
"logged_in_once"=dword:00000001
"signup_state"=dword:00000003
"version_logged_in"="1.0.0.104"
"api"="{FEC3A2F9-91C5-41B7-B17A-5356B8E882D0}"
"has_checked_orkut_picture"=dword:00000001

[hkey_current_user\software\google\Google Talk\Process]
"at"=dword:00000000
"pid"=dword:00000000
"hwnd"=dword:00000000

[hkey_current_user\software\google\GoogleToolbarNotifier]
"DSPSuspended"=dword:00000001
```

Comment: So you decided to share your password with everyone?  That doesn't seem entirely wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [this program](http://www.reactive-software.com/google-talk-password-recovery.html) to obtain the existing password, but a better solution would be to retrieve it with [Google's password assistance](http://support.google.com/talk/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=23984).

Comment: +1 for taking the time to reply. I already tried that & wrote to their tech support (still waiting). AS stated, I do not have enough info for google tech help